# questions about "::operator new"

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator, operator-keyword, delete-operator

I have recently learned about `::operator new(unsigned long)` which doesn't call the constructor and just allocates memory.

- Why should I use the `::` thing in front of it? Shouldn't I prefer using a custom overload if the user decides to make one (I assume that `::` uses the default definition of the function but I wouldn't be against a short explanation if I don't get it right)
- When I allocate a block of memory (possibly an array) with `::operator new`, does it remember the size of the block at this memory address (like `new[]` does to be able to use `delete[]` later)? That is, should I use `delete`, `operator delete(void*)` or `operator delete(void*, size_t)`, or maybe even `delete[]` ? And should I also use `::`?
- Using g++, deleting with `::operator delete(void*, size_t)` gives an error when compiling with c++11, but compiles fine with c++14. Does it mean that these operator are a new feature? The error says that it can't convert from `size_t` to `void*`. It wants to use `::operator delete(void*, void*)`.
- What even is the definition `::operator delete(void*, void*)`? Does it delete to bytes/buffers (don't know, see question 2) at once?

This is very specific and I have not found info online, but I'm trying to make a vector class and I'd like to learn this in order to use the operators in the class.

Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest time with [operator new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) and [operator delete](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) to start.

Comment: Use `::` if you want the global namespace; Use `delete[]` if you use `new[]` and do them in the same namespace.

Comment: You should not use `operator new` (with or without `::`) at all unless you are writing an allocator. This is something very few people do.

Answer (score 1):

> Why should I use the :: thing in front of it?

You should use it if you intend to use the global overload in case there are overloads in the current scope that you wish to avoid.

> When I allocate a block of memory (possibly an array) with ::operator new, does it remember the size of the block at this memory address

Practically, the implicit replaceable overload has to remember. Otherwise `operator delete(void*)` couldn't work.

> Using g++, deleting with ::operator delete(void*, size_t) gives an error when compiling with c++11, but compiles fine with c++14. Does it mean that these operator are a new feature?

That particular overload of `operator delete` was introduced in C++14.

> What even is the definition ::operator delete(void*, void*)?

Let's take a look at documentation:

> > Called by the standard single-object placement new expression if the object's constructor throws an exception. The standard library implementation of this function does nothing.

Comment: Thank you! To be clear, when you say that it has to remember the size, does that mean I can simply use “operator delete(void*)” on anything allocated with “operator new(size_t)”? I don’t understand why “operator delete(void*, size_t)” exists then.

Comment: @glugau `operator delete(void*, size_t)` exists so that a user defined overload can use a different implementation that doesn't need to store the size.